# The 100mb recovery partition of Windows 7 has gotten installed on unwanted location

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I had 2 unpartitioned blank disks in my machine before installing Win7.

I manually created 2 partitions on first disk and selected first partition for Windows installation.

Now I have discovered that Windows has put the 100mb recovery partition on the second disk.

I intended to use the disk 2 for mirroring. What shall I do with the recovery partition?

Comment: Well is it making problems for you?? Win7 needs that for restoring files if needed

Comment: The problem is he wants that entire drive to mirror the system most likely for a backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format the second disk, and recreate the recovery partition on the first one, then you can use the second disk for backup/mirror.

You may want to disconnect the second one before recreating it though, just to make sure windows doesn't decide to put it on it again.